# How do I prevent references to a readonly object from modifying the readonly object?

Tags: c#, readonly

I want to be able to provide one of my classes with a "default" value or state. We'll call that class `Foo` and it looks like this:

```
class Foo
{
    public static readonly Default = new Foo() { Bar = 42 };
    public int Bar { get; set; }
}
```

What this says is that I want the default value of an instance of `Foo` to have its member, `Bar`, set to 42. The problem occurs when I make changes to a reference to `Foo.Default`.

```
void Function()
{
    Foo temp = Foo.Default;
    temp.Bar = 101; // Foo.Default.Bar = 101

    Foo anothertemp = Foo.Default; // anothertemp.Bar = 101!!
}
```

How can I avoid this behavior?

Answer (score 1):

Make `Foo` immutable.

```
public class Foo
{
    public static readonly Foo Default = new Foo(42);

    public Foo(int bar)
    {
        Bar = bar;
    }

    public int Bar { get; private set; }
}
```

Exposing fields is considered bad practice in most cases, as it breaks encapsulation.

Answer (score 0):

For this purpose i suggest:

`public static Foo Default { get { return new Foo (){ Bar = 42 }; }` }

If any acce change Default value, other acce can use Default value(but not reference!)

Comment: +1. If Foo must be mutable, this is a decent option. I'd probably make it a static factory method named CreateWithDefaults() or some such to make it obvious to callers that it creates a new instance each time.